# UIImagePickerController black opaque bottom bar

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, autolayout

I need my view to have a Black Opaque bottom and top bar when taking a picture. I want it to look exactly like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO8Fy.jpg

This is actually what I have running my code on my iPhone 5 running iOS 7. But when I compiled my code on an iPhone 4S (iOS 7 too), the bottom bar becomes transparent - the view becomes a camera from top to bottom, like the camera app now. Even the "Take Picture" button becomes transparent, like SnapChat. I hate this. What's the setting I need to change to make the bottom bar become opaque on my iPhone 4S? I am using autolayout.

This is in my viewDidAppear:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        self.anImagePickerController = [UIImagePickerController new];
        self.anImagePickerController.delegate = self;
        self.anImagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.anImagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;

        [self presentViewController:self.anImagePickerController animated:NO completion:Nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below will do exactly what you want. I discovered this myself as I was wanting to do the exact same thing as you, and feel that rolling your own camera controller is completely unnecessary.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
imagePicker.delegate = self;

 [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^()
 {   
     for (UIView *subview in imagePicker.view.subviews)
     {
        if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UINavigationTransitionView"])
        {
            UIView *theView = (UIView *)subview;

            for (UIView *subview in theView.subviews)
            {
               if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UIViewControllerWrapperView"])
               {
                   UIView *theView = (UIView *)subview;

                    for (UIView *subview in theView.subviews)
                    {
                         if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"PLCameraView"])
                         {
                             UIView *theView = (UIView *)subview;

                             for (UIView *subview in theView.subviews)
                             {
                                 if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"CAMTopBar"])
                                 {
                                      subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                                 }
                                 if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"CAMBottomBar"])
                                 {
                                      subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                                 }
                                 if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"PLCropOverlay"])
                                 {
                                     UIView *theView = (UIView *)subview;

                                     for (UIView *subview in theView.subviews)
                                     {
                                         if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"PLCropOverlayBottomBar"])
                                         {
                                              UIView *theView = (UIView *)subview;

                                              for (UIView *subview in theView.subviews)
                                              {
                                                  if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"PLCropOverlayPreviewBottomBar"])
                                                  {
                                                      subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}];
```

Comment: Upvoted for beating the "nested curly braces" record.

Comment: Does this work in iOS6? iOS6.1? iOS7? iOS7.1b1? iOS7.1b2? iOS7.1b3? iOS7.1? iOS7.2? iOS8?

Comment: Also, including strings such as "UIViewControllerWrapperView" in your code is a good way to have your app rejected from the store.

Comment: Indeed, probably going with AVFoundation unfortunately. Ugh what a nightmare

Comment: What the hell, it really works! Thanks a lot!

By the way I'm running iOS 7 on that 3.5 inch iPhone, but will it work on iOS 6.0 3.5" iPhones?

Comment: No idea about iOS 6, as the view hierarchy may possibly be different than iOS 7. As mentioned above, this code could theoretically cause rejection from Apple, but fun code nonetheless :)

Comment: It's a terrible code to suggest to someone that doesn't know better.

Comment: Why could it be rejected by Apple? I don't think anyone here wants to have a rejected app, so why give away code that will get it rejected

Comment: It's because it uses private strings to find the private classes. For internal apps that aren't on the app store this is fine. But it's bad to do this. UIImagePicker needs more customization options badly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can modify the behavior of `UIImagePickerController`. It is likely removing the black bar due to not enough screen space on the smaller screen devices. If you insist on this behavior, you need to go the custom overlay method. You set `showsCameraControls` to `NO`, and provide a `cameraOverlayView` which will behave as you need it to. From your custom overlay view, when the user taps the button to take a picture, you call `takePicture` on the image picker controller.

You can see an example implementation of an overlay view in Apple's examples:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196

Comment: Well it's not really taking more space, because there still is a "Take Picture" button shown on the screen right. I just don't want it to be transparent - I need to somehow set it to black opaque.

Comment: You will have to implement the overlay view.

Comment: I already have a small overlay view with black background above "Take Picture" button. But if I try to make it to go lover, it hides the button. Any way to make it slide under "Take Picture" button?

Comment: No. You have to cancel the camera controls and implement them yourself.

Comment: That seems like a lot of hours. Do you have a good tutorial to recommend for this?

Comment: @anthoprotic I'll edit the question with a tutorial.

Comment: Ok. Looking forward to it

Comment: I can provide you with the code to do exactly what you want, to make the top and bottom bars opaque black in your UIImagePicker, as I have just recently did this myself in my own code.

Comment: See the answer I posted below. Works perfectly and I plan to ship an app with this code.

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePickerController is a UINavigationController. The bar you are complaining about is the UINavigationController's `toolbar`. As you surely know, a toolbar is transparent (or at least translucent) by default on iOS 7.

Comment: Hey Matt, in Interface Builder I set the Navigation Controller presenting my Camera with "Opaque Black Navigation Bar" and "Opaque Black ToolBar". Apparently it works on iPhone 5 but not on 4S (4 inch vs 3.5 inch). Any solution?

Comment: The black bar in the image picker controller, more specifically the camera controller, is not a toolbar.

Comment: But is it possible to change it's color/transparency?

Comment: @anthoprotic No. The camera controller's view hierarchy is private, and changing is not supported. You either take what is given or have to roll your own.